# How to segue from tableview cell inside child TableViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

I'm pretty new to XCode.

I have the following ViewController layout in my storyboard:

[image]

When the accessory in the cell at section 1, row 2 is tapped, I want to segue to another tableView (the final controller in the lineup) so the user can select an option.

Because the first table is embedded in a child view, I figure that I will need to push the second table onto the New Client VC navigation controller programmatically. I'll need to figure out how best to do this.

That is pretty much by-the-by at the moment, though, because the accessory, and the tableViewCell, and all the tableViewCells, appear to be dead when you tap them.

In Interface Builder, I have the New Client VC set up to use a NewClientVC custom class and its child, TableViewController, set up to use an AddClientFormTVC class. The tableView is set up to use an AddClientForm class.

In my AddClientFormTVC custom class, I have placed the following code:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath)
}
```

and this never gets called. In an attempt to discover what is going on, I placed the following line in an overridden `viewDidLoad` method in AddClientFormTVC, and it shows me that AddClientFormTVC is indeed the delegate.

```swift
print(tableView.delegate)
```

I have checked my view hierarchies to see if there is anything getting in the way of my taps, but there does not appear to be. I don't know what the weird highlighted view is down the right hand side, but it doesn't seem to be obstructing anything important.

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out why `didSelectRowAt` is not firing?

Comment: Make sure that the `UITableView` `selection` attribute is set to `Single selection` in the attribute inspector

Comment: You know what? This is the answer. I thought I had tried that and it didn't make any difference, but on reflection, I started out playing with accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith: and I'll bet I tried it with that and then forgot I changed track when I started getting confused. I found out later that accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith: is a total red herring when using disclosure indicator. TLDR: Thank you.